# How to keep values in the form after submission codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to keep the users input in the form after submission. I am using codeigniter.

```
<?php echo form_label('Email'); 

$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'email',
'placeholder'=>'enter email',
set_value('email')

);

echo form_input($data );
```

Comment: you need to insert them to a database to save them

Comment: I want to make the user input stay in the text box, I do not want to get values from my database

Comment: Use ajax, use type=button and send to server on click that button.